# Sequence defined as sum.

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}$. Prove that this sequence is Cauchy.

I know that this is the partial sum of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$ wich converges, but I don't know how to prove this, without using this fact, I mean, prove it by definition $|a_n-a_m|< \varepsilon$.

Comment: We have that for any $a_n \to L \in \mathbb{R} \implies $ $a_n$ is Cauchy.

Comment: I know, but I can't realize how this sequence converges.

Comment: It converges by Leibniz of course.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I can't use the series in order to prove the convergence of the sequence, I have to expand and show that the diference of the terms $a_n$ and $a_m$ is less than every $\varepsilon$. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Ah ok! Now that's clear.

Comment: Just notice that for $n>m$, $|a_n-a_m|\leq \frac{1}{m!}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $m\geq n$. Then you have

$|a_m-a_n|=|\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}|=|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}+\sum_{k=n}^{m-1}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}|=|\sum_{k=n}^{m-1}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}|\leq\sum_{k=n}^{m-1}\frac{1}{k!}<\epsilon$